Show that orthogonal matrix maps to Borel $\sigma$-algebra

Let be $L:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ an orthogonal matrix and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra. Show that if $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ then $L(A)\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.


We already know that $L$ is a bijective function, maps open sets to open sets and that $\mathcal{E}$, the family of all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, generates $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, i.e. $\sigma(\mathcal{E})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
Our sample solution simply says
$$
L(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))=L(\sigma(\mathcal{E}))\overset{??}{=}\sigma(L(\mathcal{E}))\subset \sigma(\mathcal{E})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d).
$$
I have no idea why the second equal sign holds. The usual straightforward way by picking an $A\in L(\sigma(\mathcal{E}))$ and trying to show that it implies $A\in \sigma(L(\mathcal{E}))$ seems to be a dead end.
Can someone explain this step to me?

${A: L(A)\in \sigma (L(\mathcal E)}$ is a $\sigma-$ algebra which contains $\mathcal E$ io it contains $\sigma(\mathcal E)$.

@geetha290krm, if I understand your comment correctly then this shows $L(\sigma(\mathcal{E}))\subset\sigma(L(\mathcal{E}))$. However, I am not able to show the reverse relation $$L(\sigma(\mathcal{E}))\supset\sigma(L(\mathcal{E})).$$ Actually, the reverse relation is not necessary to prove the statement and as $L(\mathcal{E})=\mathcal{E}$, I suspect that there is a typo in the sample solution and it should be instead $$L(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))=L(\sigma(\mathcal{E}))\subset\sigma(L(\mathcal{E}))=\sigma(\mathcal{E})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d).$$ What do you mean?

The reverse inclusion is easier. Since $L$ is a bijection, $L(\sigma (\mathcal E))$ is a  $\sigma$ algebra and it contains $L(\mathcal E)$.

@geetha290krm, oh ok I didn't see it. But it's legit to replace the $\subset$-sign in the sample solution so that we have $$L(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))=L(\sigma(\mathcal{E}))=\sigma(L(\mathcal{E}))=\sigma(\mathcal{E})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d),$$ right?
